# How do I make 3 buttons to choose different parameters

Tags: javascript, html, button

So my code is like this and I want to choose every button different parameter in my head this makes sense but it doesn't work that way, what is correct syntax?
because if I click start(Easy) button it should count as undefined which should start first parameter no? if Normal is undefined it should start second one, I don't know why this doesn't work

```
<button type="button" onclick="start(Easy)" id="startEasy">Lahká</button>
<button type="button" onclick="start(Normal)" id="startNormal">Stredná</button>
<button type="button" onclick="start(Hard)" id="startHard">Tážká</button>

  function start(Easy, Normal, Hard) {
        if (Easy === undefined) {
        document.getElementById("diffi").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startNormal").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startHard").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startEasy").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hideEasy").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("gratulujem").innerHTML = "Zadajťe hodnotu:";
        document.getElementById("rules").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("numbEasy").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("pocet").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedEasy").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedNormal").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedHard").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("numbEasy").focus();
        document.getElementById("odpovedEasy").innerHTML = "Zadajte číslo 1..20";
        document.getElementById("vsetko").style.maxHeight = "350px";
        }
      else if (Normal === undefined) {
        document.getElementById("diffi").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startNormal").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startHard").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startEasy").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hideNormal").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("gratulujem").innerHTML = "Zadajťe hodnotu:";
        document.getElementById("rules").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("numbNormal").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("pocet").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedEasy").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedNormal").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedHard").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("numbNormal").focus();
        document.getElementById("odpovedNormal").innerHTML = "Zadajte číslo 1..50";
        document.getElementById("vsetko").style.maxHeight = "350px";
        }
      else {
        document.getElementById("diffi").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startNormal").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startHard").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startEasy").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hideHard").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("gratulujem").innerHTML = "Zadajťe hodnotu:";
        document.getElementById("rules").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("numbHard").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("pocet").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedEasy").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedNormal").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedHard").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("numbHard").focus();
        document.getElementById("odpovedHard").innerHTML = "Zadajte číslo 1..100";
        document.getElementById("vsetko").style.maxHeight = "350px";
      }
  }
```

Comment: `function start(option) {`    ->  `if (options === "Easy") {`   -> `onclick="start('Hard')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution :

```
<button type="button" onclick="Start('easy')" id="startEasy">Lahká</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Start('normal')" id="startNormal">Stredná</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Start('hard')" id="startHard">Tážká</button>

function Start(mode)
{
   switch(mode)
   {
     case 'easy' :
       // Do it easy.
       break;

     case 'normal' :
       // Do it normal.
       break;

     case 'hard' :
       // Do it hard.
       break;

     // In this case undefined and default is the same thing,
     // This can be simplified just by default.
     // case 'undefined' :
     default :
      // Do it as you want if undefined.
      // Do it easy for example.
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: this worked extremly well , thank you, now i just have, i am just beginner and learning this makes my work so much easier

Comment: @Picarica yes, this is a correct solution, but if you go with this, you end up duplicating your code. Please check out my answer and write your code only once. You future self will thank you.

Comment: It is better to think SWITCH when you you have more than one IF. It is not always possible, but code is more flexible and readable. And create 3 functions easy(); normal(); hard(); which you can call in the case to not have to duplicate code. Just call the right function ;)

Comment: For better security: you should not use inline javascript. Instead of onclick, the JS code should be in a js file, which adds the functions to the elements via their IDs.

Comment: @Shim-Sao I was not suggesting to use if instead of switch. My suggestion was to use a single code for all three cases. Your suggestion still duplicates code. For example, instead of "odpovedEasy" in the first case, "odpovedNormal" in the second case and "odpovedHard" in the third case one can simply write "odpoved" + mode (provided that you change the value of mode to start with a uppercase letter). Please consult my answer and see how code duplication can be avoided. Your answer is correct, but not the best.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad. I know, my response just concerns the question to pass an argument to a function and how to treat different case and undefined, not for code optimization because I think it can/will be involve so I must confess not having to look at the gall of the code. Your answer is good for optimization but 2 corrections to do : replace var difficult = 'Difficult' by var Hard = 'Difficult' and in : function start(difficulty) { if(difficulty == 'undefined') difficulty = Normal; ... } . In your case : start(Hard) will fail by undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `function` with three parameters and for each button, you attempt to pass a value for the first parameter, but those values are `undefined`. You need to define those values first (I will define the values globally, for the sake of simplicity, but later you can refactor your code):

```
var Easy = 'Easy';
var Normal = 'Normal';
var difficult = 'Difficult';
```

and then these buttons should work:

```
<button type="button" onclick="start(Easy)" id="startEasy">Lahká</button>
<button type="button" onclick="start(Normal)" id="startNormal">Stredná</button>
<button type="button" onclick="start(Hard)" id="startHard">Tážká</button>
```

We can simplify your `function` a lot, for example you do not need `if` or `switch`, just use the parameter you have received:

```
  function start(difficulty) {
        document.getElementById("diffi").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startNormal").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startHard").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("startEasy").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("hide" + difficulty).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("gratulujem").innerHTML = "Zadajťe hodnotu:";
        document.getElementById("rules").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("numb" + difficulty).style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("pocet").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedEasy").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedNormal").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("odpovedHard").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("numb" + difficulty).focus();
        document.getElementById("odpoved" + difficulty).innerHTML = "Zadajte číslo 1..20";
        document.getElementById("vsetko").style.maxHeight = "350px";
  }
```